# Get value back to page without refreshing and pass it to a VAR

Tags: php, jquery

I want to update a url and pass it to the same page without refreshing the page.
At the same time i then want the page to read the VAR again and update it.
I need the PHP to use the var in the url on same page to read data in other classes im using.
My page name is varydates.php and i need to get the year from a dropdown box.
I had look at this code but its not working.
Im kind new to jquery with php.

```
$("#year_select").change(function() {
var link = $(this).val();
var newUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'varydates.php&ampyr_select="+link;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>varydates.php&ampyr_select="+link,
    data: { newlink: link },
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
  });
});



<?php $link=$_GET['newlink'];?>
```

Comment: `&ampyr_select` will not do what you expect, to note the obvious. If you want to update a part of the page, you'll want to make an AJAX request to a separate script handling that concern, not to the main page itself. If you did reload the whole page via AJAX, you might as well just refresh the page. Let's try this: *What do you actually want to accomplish?* Instead of _what you're trying to do_.

Comment: I know the PHP is on server side. Im trying to find out is there a wat to pass a value received from the  ajax int a variable on the page to be able to do somthing like this again <?php $link=$_GET['newlink'];?>

Comment: You realize that in order to update the page _without refreshing_, you have to both pass a value to PHP _and_ receive a value that your JS function updates to the DOM. That's why I'm saying that _you should have a separate script that responds to AJAX calls_.